# Cocoa: Masking NSTableView with rounded bottom corners

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview, cornerradius

I'm trying to figure out how to mask an NSTableView with bottom rounded corners - but only at the bottom.

In this image, no effects are applied:

[image: The bottom corners are square]

In these images, you can see the corners rounded, I've used this code for the corners:

```
self.scrollView.wantsLayer = TRUE;
self.scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
```

[image: top corners and bottom corners rounded]

What I cannot figure out is how to get rid of the rounded corners on the top left and top right:

[image: corners are rounded]

I've tried a few different options to no avail:

```
//creating a path
//this is a category from github.com/iccir/XUIKit
NSBezierPath * path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.tableView.bounds byRoundingCorners:XUIRectCornerBottomLeft|XUIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(6, 6)];
CAShapeLayer * layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
layer.fillColor = [[NSColor blackColor] CGColor];
layer.path = [path CGPath];

//attempt 1
self.scrollView.contentView.wantsLayer = TRUE;
self.scrollView.contentView.layer.mask = layer;
self.scrollView.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;

//attempt 2
((NSView*)self.scrollView.documentView).wantsLayer = TRUE;
((NSView*)self.scrollView.documentView).layer.mask = layer;
((NSView*)self.scrollView.documentView).layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;

//attempt 3
self.scrollView.wantsLayer = TRUE;
self.scrollView.layer.mask = layer;
self.scrollView.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
```

What ends up happening is everything disappears:

[image: table view content is gone]

Anyone have any idea how to properly handle this? Thanks!

Comment: What's the parent view of your scroll view? Have you tried rounding its bottom corners? It should clip anything it contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i figured it out. This code works:

```
//creating a path
//github.com/iccir/XUIKit
NSBezierPath * path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0,0,325,80) byRoundingCorners:XUIRectCornerBottomLeft|XUIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(6, 6)];
CAShapeLayer * layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
layer.path = [path CGPath];
self.scrollView.wantsLayer = TRUE;
self.scrollView.layer.mask = layer;
```

My issue was the path I was creating originally had a .height of 0.

Also note that if the table view changes size, the layer mask has to change as well.

Comment: osx doesn't have this API "bezierPathWithRoundedRect: byRoundingCorners", how do you use it?

Comment: @jimwan In my code comments I point to XUIKit - github.com/iccir/XUIKit